# GCP cloud storage still caches public object after specifying cache-control header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using the cloud storage REST api to upload the image to the bucket, which is public to allUsers. When uploading a different image with the same object name it overwrites it on GCP, but the public link still displays the old object. I tried setting the Cache-Control header of the request to "no-store", but the problem still persisted. The metadata of the object (on the GCP UI) shows no field supplied in the Cache-Control. How can I force it to refresh the file at once?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [cache directives](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cache_control_directives) for no - store A response with no-store isn't cached. This can be overridden on a per-backend basis with the FORCE_CACHE_ALL cache mode.

By default, when the entire bucket is public, or the individual objects are public and the individual objects don't specify Cache-Control metadata, Cloud Storage assigns a Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600 header to the object. You can set different values by using [Cache-Control metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control).
By setting the max age value less this may help you in resolving your issue.

Comment: This is what I tried doing, I added the Cache-Control header and tried no-store,no-cache or a low max-age, but the object metadata showed nothing in the Cache-Control field, and it was still behaving the same

Comment: Can you check this Cache control methods [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#cachecontrol) might give some idea in resolving this issue.

Comment: I did use the valid Cache-Control no-cache header as indicated, the public url still returns the older object state

Comment: You can try adding a unique query parameter to the URL when accessing the object. This would effectively create a new URL for the object, and the browser would no longer be able to use a cached version of the object. Another way could be to set the Cache-Control header to a short value, like "max-age=1" which will force the browser to re-fetch the object after 1 second. It's also worth checking if you have any CDN or reverse proxy in front of your storage bucket. If so, you might need to clear the cache there as well.

Comment: A unique name would be a cheap way out of what I am trying to do, since that means I will have to save the link instead of recreating the link whenever I need the object. It is my go to way if there is truly no way for not caching objects on GCP easily, it seems like a weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Google caches Bucket exposed backends into various caches. I can see 3-4 versions of the file an each request. I don't know how to reset this behavior, following seems doesn't have effect if CDN is not enabled:

```
gcloud compute backend-buckets update web-app \
  --default-ttl=0 --max-ttl=0 --client-ttl=0 --cache-mode=CACHE_ALL_STATIC
```

One of the following helped at least to disable client side caching (`curl -v` started to show `Cache-Control: max-age=0` after some random time, like 15 minutes, GCP is inconsistent in propagating data across infra):

```
gcloud compute backend-buckets update web-app \
  --custom-response-header 'Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0'

gsutil -h "Cache-Control: public,max-age=0" cp *.html gs://web-app/
```